# How do I make my player idle or add speed for when im moving up or down in Unity(2021)?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Here's my code for player movement. I have set up walking around and I am now Trying to change the sprite animation when walking in different directions. Everything was working fine but when I tried to change the sprite for walking up the sprite gets stuck in a loop and doesn't idle.

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Animator Animator;

    [SerializeField] private float speed = 1f;

    private Rigidbody2D body;
    private Vector2 axisMovement;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        body = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        axisMovement.x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        axisMovement.y = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

        Animator.SetFloat("Speed", Mathf.Abs(axisMovement.x));

         if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
         {
            Animator.SetBool("isforward", true);
         }
         if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
         {
            Animator.SetBool("isforward", false);
         }
         if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
         {
            Animator.SetBool("isforward", false);
         }
           if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
         {
            Animator.SetBool("isforward", false);
         }
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Move();
    }

    private void Move()
    {
        body.velocity = axisMovement.normalized * speed;
        CheckForFlipping();
    }

    private void CheckForFlipping()
    {
        bool movingLeft = axisMovement.x < 0;
        bool movingRight = axisMovement.x > 0;

        if (movingLeft)
        {
            transform.localScale = new Vector3(-1f, transform.localScale.y);
        }

        if (movingRight)
        {
            transform.localScale = new Vector3(1f, transform.localScale.y);
        }        
    }
}
```

I also tried doing Animator.SetFloat("Speed", Mathf.Abs(axisMovement.x)); but switch it with axisMovement.y but that stops all the animations moving left and right stop working.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out. here's the updated code

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Animator Animator;

    [SerializeField] private float speed = 1f;

    private Rigidbody2D body;
    private Vector2 axisMovement;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        body = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        axisMovement.x = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        axisMovement.y = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

        Animator.SetFloat("Speed", Mathf.Abs(axisMovement.x + axisMovement.y));

          if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
          {
             Animator.SetBool("isforward", true);
          } else {
            Animator.SetBool("isforward", false);
          }
        //  if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
        //  {
        //     Animator.SetBool("isforward", false);
        //  }
        //  if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
        //  {
        //     Animator.SetBool("isforward", false);
        //  }
        //    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
        //  {
        //     Animator.SetBool("isforward", false);
        //  }
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Move();
    }

    private void Move()
    {
        body.velocity = axisMovement.normalized * speed;
        CheckForFlipping();
    }

    private void CheckForFlipping()
    {
        bool movingLeft = axisMovement.x < 0;
        bool movingRight = axisMovement.x > 0;

        if (movingLeft)
        {
            transform.localScale = new Vector3(-1f, transform.localScale.y);
        }

        if (movingRight)
        {
            transform.localScale = new Vector3(1f, transform.localScale.y);
        }        
    }
}
```

Comment: What about simply `Animator.SetBool("isforward", Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W));` ;) also .. afaik per default the axis `"Vertical"` also applies to the keys `W` and `S` so you could probably as well just go  `Animator.SetBool("isforward", axisMovement.y > 0f);`